# Double or Take game

Tags: game, number-theory, nim

*Double or Take* is a two-player number game. Alice starts by selecting any positive integer. Bob's options are to:

- subtract a positive perfect square
- subtract a positive perfect cube, or
- double the number.

Alice then takes the result, and has the same options. Play alternates, with the winner being the first player to reach exactly zero.

**What are the possible starting numbers between $1$ and $11$ that  Alice could choose to be sure that she can beat Bob?**

And as a bonus (it's not essential to answer this, and may be tedious with pencil and paper): **can Alice be sure of beating Bob if she chooses $12$ as the starting number?**

Comment: Source for the game: Martin Gardner in a 1970's *Sci.Am*. column, I think, though I'm now unable to locate it. If anyone can find the exact column I'd be very grateful.

Comment: "reaching zero" implies exactly zero? As in not going beyond zero to a negative integer?

Comment: That's right. Players are not allowed to end up with a negative number.

Comment: I do have the answer for 12, but as there are a lot of possible plays it would be lengthy to set them all out in full. And maybe not that interesting.

Comment: I'm still looking at the situation starting at 12, and you're not wrong about it being tedious with pencil and paper. How do you feel about computer-assisted solutions to this one?

Comment: Yes please do. You'll find you have to double a surprising number of times before the answer comes out.

Comment: Can the perfect square or perfect cube be 1?

Comment: Yes of course, 1 is valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer to the non-bonus part:

> Next-player winning positions -- i.e., ones where Bob wins if he starts -- from 1 to 11 inclusive are 1,3,4,6,8,9,10,11. Next-player losing positions are 2,5,7. So Alice (who plays second) wins if she chooses 2, 5, or 7, but not if she chooses any other number from 1 to 11.

Proof:

> Call a position "winning" or "losing" according to what happens with best play to the player whose move it is. (Or "drawing" if neither player can force a win and at least one can force the game to continue for ever.) Then we find, successively:
>  0 is losing (whoever just moved there already won the game).
>  1,4,8,9 are winning (you can move to 0 from any of them).
>  2 is losing (you can move from there only to 1,4, both of which are winning).
>  3,6,10 are winning (you can move to 2 from any of them).
>  5 is losing (you can move from there only to 1,4,10, all of which are winning).
>  14 is winning (you can move to 5 from it).
>  7 is losing (you can move from there only to 3,6,14, all of which are winning).
>  11 is winning (you can move to 7 from it).

Bonus part: From 12

> it turns out -- I calculated this by computer -- that the sort of reasoning above is enough to determine that all positions you can get to from 12 *other than 24* are next-player wins, and all positions you can get to from 24 *other than 48* are next-player wins. Now, we have $12\rightarrow24\rightarrow48\rightarrow12$. So, if Bob loses starting from 12 in particular he must lose when he moves to 24; if Alice wins starting at 24 then it must be by moving to 48 (since all her other moves from 24 lose); if Bob loses when starting at 48 then in particular he must lose by moving to 12, i.e., Alice must win when starting from 12. But this is a contradiction since we started out by supposing that 12 is a *loss* for the player moving there.

Hence

> Alice *cannot* be sure of winning if she makes Bob move first from 12. He will move to 24, Alice definitely loses if she moves to anything other than 48, and then *either* Bob can win by doing something other than moving back to 12 (in which case he should) *or* he can't (in which case he should move back to 12, and then the best Alice can do is to go around the same loop again).

Comment: I didn’t look at this answer when composing mine below, but I came to the same conclusion as @MichaelMaggs. Sorry, Gareth!

Comment: @El-Guest Not sure what you're apologizing for.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan for (potentially) nipping your answer.

Comment: Oh! I confess it hadn't occurred to me that that was a danger; I had an essentially correct answer some time before yours, after all. But of course OP can award the checkmark on whatever basis he pleases...

Comment: It’s yours, for sure — you were essentially correct before me. 12 is extremely sticky, I’m finding...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan. Accepted as the first of the two correct answers. Did you get anywhere with 12? I did wonder about posting that as a separate question, but maybe it would be considered ‘just calculation’ with insufficient puzzling interest.

Comment: I established that "easy" calculation up to, say, 100k is not enough to resolve it as a first-player or second-player win. I also established that another slightly-less-easy heuristic for identifying some drawn positions isn't enough to resolve it as drawn. However, we have 12 -> 24 -> 48 -> 12 which means that if 12 is a definite loss then 24 must be a win; I forget whether I eliminated all moves from 24 other than to 48 as possible wins, but if I did then we could deduce that 48 is a definite loss and therefore that 12 is a win, contradiction. BUT [... continues]

Comment: ... I've thrown away the bits of paper on which I did some hand calculations and restarted the computer on which I did some not-hand calculations without saving the relevant stuff. I might do it again and see whether indeed the other moves from 24 can be eliminated -- I think they might be.

Comment: @MichaelMaggs Is there a particular reason why you un-accepted this? (For the avoidance of doubt, you're perfectly within your rights to accept, not-accept, accept then un-accept, etc., whatever answers you please. I'm just curious.)

Comment: Didn’t realise I had, sorry. All sorts of bad things happen when I look at things on a phone.

Answer (score 4):

Let’s see: I assume that all numbers must be greater than or equal to zero, otherwise the possibilities become too painful. If that was the intention, I’ll look harder.

1

> Bob subtracts 1, so Alice loses.

2

> Bob can’t double, because that leads to 4 and a Bob-loss; he can’t subtract 1 because that leads to 1 and a Bob-loss. Therefore 2 is a winning number for Alice.

3

> Bob subtracts 1, forcing a loss for Alice as above.

4

> Bob subtracts 4 and Alice loses.

5

> Bob can’t subtract either 1 or 4, since Alice can win. He also can’t double, because that makes 10 — then Alice subtracts 8 forcing a Bob-loss. Therefore 5 is a winning number for Alice.

6

> Bob subtracts 4, forcing a loss for Alice as 2 is left.

7

> If Bob subtracts 1, Alice subtracts 4, forcing a loss for Bob. If Bob subtracts 4, Alice subtracts 1, forcing a loss for Bob. Bob therefore has to double to 14. But Bob doubling to 14 means Alice can subtract 9 to get to 5, which forces a Bob-loss. Thus 7 is a winning number for Alice.

8

> Bob subtracts 8 ($2^3$) and Alice loses.

9

> Bob subtracts 4, forcing a loss for Alice as 5 is left.

10

> Bob subtracts 8, leading to an Alice loss.

11

> Bob subtracts 4, leading to an Alice loss.

Therefore the only starting numbers that win for Alice are

> 2, 5, and 7.

Bonus Part: 12

> Bob has to double to 24 because he can’t get to 2, 5, or 7. Then Alice can’t subtract 1, because it’ll leave Bob with 23; he can subtract 16 and win. Alice can’t subtract 9, because it’ll leave Bob with 15; he can subtract 8 and win. Alice can’t subtract 8, because it’ll leave Bob with 16; he can subtract 9 and win. Alice can’t subtract 16, because it’ll leave Bob with 8; he can subtract 1 and win. **Doubling here allows Bob to subtract 36 and leave Alice with 12. It appears then that this could create a stable loop solution where neither player wins.** If Alice subtracts 4, Bob is left with 20. Bob can’t subtract 4, because leaving 16 allows Alice to subtract 9 and get to 7. Bob can’t subtract 9, because leaving 11 allows Alice to subtract 4 and get to 7. Bob can’t subtract 16 because it leaves 4 for Alice. **However, subtracting 8 leaves an equilibrium standoff solution. This might be optimal...?**

Comment: That's correct for the main question but not for the bonus.

Answer (score 0):

TL; DR:

> Bob cannot force a win on 12, but has a nonlosing strategy.

We use a notation X-> Y to indicate that a move from number X to number Y is possible, and X->Win to indicate that the current player can force a win if the current number is X. Moving to a winning move is a losing move, as then the other player can win. Similarly, we have X-> Lose.

With this, we build a partial game tree. Formatting was a bit of an adventure, so... sorry for the mess?

Base cases:

> Based no Gareth's (correct) answer, we have
> 1->Win
> 2->Lose
> 3->Win
> 4->Win
> 5->Lose
> 6->Win
> 7->Lose
> 8->Win
> 9->Win
> 10->Win
> 11->Win
> 14->Win

Turn 1:

> The cubes and squares less than 12 are: 1, 4, 8, 9
> We can infer the moves
> 12->11
> 12->8
> 12->4
> 12->3
> All losing moves, which can be disregarded (as a rational player will ignore them)
> Also, 12-> 24, which we will eventually find forces the next player to lose or enter a loop.

Turn 2:

> Carrying on in this fashion to build a more complete game tree,
> 24-> 8 (Losing)
> 24-> 15 (Losing- see below)
> 24-> 16 (Losing, next player can remove 16)
> 24-> 20  (Losing, see below)
> 24-> 23  (Losing- see below)
> 24-> 48  (Loops to self or 12 in 2 moves, or to 12 in 1 move)
> As all these moves are losing except for 48, the active player must move to 48

Turn 3:

> 15-> 7 (Win- Having found a winning move, we can infer that 15 is a winning position and terminate this branch)
>
> 20-> 19 (Winning- see below)
>
> 23 -> 7 (Winning)
> We can subtract 1,4,8,9,16,25,27, or 36 from 48, allowing move
> 48 -> 12 (Loop, changing turn parity)
> 48 -> 39 (Loops to 12 in 1 move)
> 48 -> 40 (Loops to 24 in 1 move)
> 48 -> 44 (Losing)
> 48 -> 47 (Losing)

Turn 4:

> 19-> 3 (Losing)
> 19-> 10 (Losing)
> 19->11 (Losing)
> 19-> 15 (Losing)
> 19 -> 18 (Losing- see below)
> 19 -> 38 (Losing- see below)
> All moves here are losing, so moving to 19 is a Winning move.
> 21 -> 5 (Winning)
> 23 -> 7 (Winning)
> 32 -> 7 (Winning)
> 39 -> 12 (Loop, retaining player parity)
> 40 -> 24 (Loop, changing player parity)
> 44 -> 17 (Win)
> 47 -> 5 (Win)

Turn 5:

> We can subtract 1, 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, or 36 from 38, allowing move
> 38 -> 2 (Winning)
>
> 18-> 2 (Winning)
> 13-> 5 (Winning)
> 15-> 7 (Winning)
> 17-> 1 (L)
> 17 -> 8 (L)
> 17 -> 9 (L)
> 17 -> 13 (L)
> 17 -> 16 (L)
> 17 -> 34 (L)

Turn 6:

> 34-> 7 (W)

Comment: $48 - 19 = 29$.

Comment: Curses, foiled by arithmatic. I'll see if I can fix this real quick.